# How can I count flings / swipes on a Android Gallery View?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-gallery

I'm using a Gallery (android.widget.gallery) with an ImageAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. I need to count all User-Interactions with this Gallery. I count the Clicks within an OnClickListener, but how can I count the Flings / Swipes?

I hope you can give me an hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to subclass `Gallery`, and override the methods you need, such as `onFling`, `onDown`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I tried this before by overriding the onFling-method, but now i overrided the onDown Method and so I can count the clicks and swipes.